# Android Layout - Dual Horizontal Scroll views

Tags: android-layout

Is it possible (anything's possible, right!) to create dual horizontal scroll views on one layout screen?

As an example....I would like two (or three) row or icons that scroll independently. I see this type of behavior on apps like Pulse.

Help with layout code please... here is my single hor. scroll...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="100dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon1" >
            </ImageButton>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon2" >
            </ImageButton>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="100dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon3" >
            </ImageButton>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon4" >
            </ImageButton>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

******Updated Code still not working... Maybe the height/width properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution this is working fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:layout_width="100dp">
       <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageButton>
       </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp" >
       <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

           <ImageButton
               android:id="@+id/ImageButton3"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

try this  enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

Just put two or more scrolls in one `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" ...>
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="100dp" .../>
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_height="100dp" .../>
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```